# Is it possible to check for an integer when using embedded elixir on the front end?

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to figure out what I can use on the embedded elixir front to check if something is a number.

This is my code

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<!--- CAN I CHECK if @action is integer here? -->
  <%=if Integer.parse(@action) %>

  <div class="form-item">
    <%= label f, :shipping_address, class: "is-req" %>
    <%= text_input f, :sender_address %>
    <%= error_tag f, :label %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <%= label f, :Receiver_Group_Name, class: "is-req" %>
    <%= text_input f, :reciever_group_name %>
    <%= error_tag f, :reciever_group_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <%= label f, :Shipping_Items, class: "is-req" %>
    <%= text_input f, :items %>
    <%= error_tag f, :items %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <%= label f, :Funding, class: "is-req" %>
    <%= text_input f, :funding %>
    <%= error_tag f, :funding %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-item is-text-center">
    <%= submit "Submit", class: "button is-big" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So I already know Integer.parse() doesn't work on the front end, but is there anything similar I could use to check a variable? Is there a way I can interface the @action with javascript if not?

First project with elixir/Phoenix, any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I already know `Integer.parse()` doesn't work on the front end”

I doubt I follow what is supposed to mean. The template is processed on the backend side. [`Integer.parse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2) *always* returns truthy values, making `if Integer.parse(whatever)` basically a NoOp.

What do you probably want is to setup another *assign* in your controller:

```
it_is_integer =
  case Integer.parse(action) do
    {_int, ""} -> true
    {_int, _} -> false
    :error -> false
  end
```

and pass this assign to [`Phoenix.Controller.render/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/3), or wherever as (`it_is_integer: it_is_integer`) and use in your template:

```
<%= if @it_is_integer %>
```

---

*Sidenote:* I am not familiar with Phoenix, but AFAICT `@action` is [never supposed to be an integer](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#form_for/4).

Comment: you are right about action, I was just checking. This works, thank you!